# Why Do Replication Deletes Require sysadmin Access

Tags: sql-server, replication, merge-replication

I am running merge replication with SQL 2012.

There seems to be a nasty consequence of the delete triggers added for replication in SQL 2012.

Inside the delete triggers are this,

```
select @xe_message = CAST('replica_id: ' + convert(nvarchar(100), @replnick) + ', article_id: ' + convert(nvarchar(100), @tablenick) + ', rowguid: ' + case when @article_rows_deleted = 1 then convert(nvarchar(100), @rowguid) else N'0' end + ', generation: ' + case when @is_mergeagent = 1 then N'0' else convert(nvarchar(100), @newgen) end + ', Reason: -1' AS varbinary(1000));
        exec master..sp_repl_generateevent 1, N'Event : ppm_insert', @xe_message
```

And an error occurs when someone does a delete if they are not in the sysadmin role,

```
Msg 8189, Level 14, State 10, Procedure sp_repl_generateevent, Line 1
You do not have permission to run 'SP_TRACE_GENERATEEVENT'.
```

So are you telling me that every user of my database has to have sysadmin access if they are going to be doing deletes?

This seems wrong. Is there a way to turn this tracing off or an alternative way to remove this requirement?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> So are you telling me that **every user of my database has to have sysadmin access** if they are going to be doing deletes?

No, as per [BOL's documentation on sp_trace_generateevent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177548.aspx):

> User must have **`ALTER TRACE`** permission.

Answer (score 2):

This is now a known bug (present only in SQL 2012), that Microsoft is currently addressing. Workaround is to give user `ALTER TRACE` permission until is resolved.

You can track status on [Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/798824/sql-server-2012-merge-replication-deletes-on-filtered-articles-with-precomputed-partitions-fail-for-users-who-do-not-have-alter-trace-permission).

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been addressed ([KB3155209](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3155209)) in SQL Server 2012 SP2 CU12